# SED and DATE in Solaris 11

Tags: sed

```
admin@mac:/app/$ fetch=$(zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/datetime; strftime "%b %d %R" $((EPOCHSECONDS - 5*60))')

admin@mac:/app/$ echo $fetch Nov 21 08:22
admin@mac:/app/$ sed -n '/$fetch/,$p' test.log 
admin@mac:/app/$(Not showing result)
```

My test.log input file below,

```
Mon Nov 21 08:22 MYT 2020,Test 1 
Mon Nov 21 08:22 MYT 2020,Test 2 
Mon Nov 21 08:22 MYT 2020,Test 3
```

Comment: Shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes - try `sed -n "/$fetch/"',$p'` or `sed -n "/$fetch/,\$p"`

Comment: There is no question here. Just some code. Edit question to tell us what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Hi This is my date format in my file "[1/24/21 9:19:20:183 MYT] ".How do i search this date using sed command.??Any idea?

Comment: Hi This is my date format in my file "[1/24/21 9:19:20:183 MYT] ".How do i search this date using sed command.??Any idea?